# Testflight SDK missing reports

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, testflight

I've installed Testflight SDK for my iOS application. 
Followed the manual in every step. The problem is -  I don't get any reports from application. No session reports, errors, feedbacks - nothing. I've checked Team Token - everything matches.

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   

    //bla bla bla some initialization code

    [TestFlight takeOff:@"my team token"];
    [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];

    TFLog(@"Test message");

    return YES;
}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: `-uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated.  Didn't you hear the stink about it on the news a month ago?

Comment: I use UDID only with debug version of archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log should print out a "Started session" or "Team token recognized" message. If so and it still doesn't work then it's probably a problem on TestFlight's side. I contacted them about a similar issue and they responded promptly with the fact that they are trying to flush all the bugs out of their system and this will result in some instability for a little while. I sometimes get messages and sometimes not. Hopefully they'll get it fixed soon. I don't think the uniqueIdentifier thing has much to do with it, but I guess it doesn't hurt to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will resolve your problem, or if you might already have resolved it yourself.
The documentation states you must call `setDeviceIdentifier` before `takeOff`.
In case this is crucial to the API, then it will never know who started the app since the identifier is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the device identifier setting.