# What conditions must be met for TestFlight to send activities to the server?

Tags: android, testflight

I'm trying to understand: **On Android, How does TestFlight determine that it is in a beta-tester environment, and should upload activity to the TestFlight server?**  There have been some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739993/what-can-prevent-testflight-from-uploading-logs) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874100/testflight-sdk-missing-reports?rq=1) asking about TestFlight on iOS, but none related to Android.

I've integrated the [TestFlight SDK](http://testflightapp.com) into my company's Android app because it looked like a great solution for beta-testing and remote logging (we already use it for iOS), but I'm can't get it to actually send the session information to the TestFlight server.  Once I install my app through the TestFlight app, I immediately see that it was installed through the TestFlight web console, and then... nada.  I get no session data or remote logs, even though I clearly should be getting something.

What I have done so far:

- Quadruple-checked my TestFlight api key
- Verified for certain that `TestFlight.takeOff()` is getting called
- Verified that `TestFlight.isActive()` reports `true`
- Tried signing the apk with the debug-only key
- Tried signing the apk with our release key
- Checked the android log for errors related to TestFlight (none)
- Contacted TestFlight support a couple days ago (I've made contact, but no progress yet)

My current guess is that the TestFlight lib thinks it is in a production environment, and therefore it should not be uploading logs and session information.

The [SDK Documentation](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/android/doc/1.0/) has nothing to offer to answer this question, but I feel that if I understood what conditions it is looking for I could nail this down pretty quickly.

I poked into TestFlightLib.jar and found that `TestFlight.isActive()` is really only reporting whether or not you've already called `TestFlight.takeOff()`, so that's not a good indicator of whether the whole system is working.

Comment: What do the friendly folks at http://help.testflightapp.com/ say about your problem?

Comment: They suggested re-signing the app with the debug key, which did not make a difference.  I've engaged with them over Twitter and through their email support.

Comment: I should add, I've also trolled through the TestFlight SDK knowledge-base at length without any luck.  The vast majority of articles there are iOS-focused, and the limited number of Android-related articles did not give me any insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** per [Isra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506062/83715) below, it looks like my first point (batching checkpoints) may no longer be valid.

After trading a few emails with TestFlight support, I am seeing events and have a better understand of what is going on.  There are two issues:

1. TestFlight for Android batches `checkpoint` events and sends them to the server once 10 or more events are collected.  Events are not preserved across app process lifetimes.  My test app was only creating two or three checkpoints, thus nothing ever got sent to the server.
2. There is an apparent issue where log events are not posted to the server *at all* unless the TestFlight session is explicitly ended with `TestFlight.endSession()`

So, the workaround (for now) is to explicitly call `TestFlight.endSession()` periodically.  Hopefully TestFlight will change (or at least document) this behavior in future releases of the library.

Comment: You're a life saver. I lost about 2 hours trying to figure out why there are no log entries. Thanks for taking the time to contact their support team.

Comment: I have lost more than 2 hours trying to solve this! I am new to android as well which is a double whammy trying to get this to work. How often do you call the TestFlight.endSession()? Do you need to call a takeOff() directly after? Any help appreciated, I'm finding android semantics a LOT more difficult than IOS at the moment :/

Comment: I gave up on TestFlight pretty quickly after posting this answer.  We moved to Crashlytics for remote logging and crash reports, and I couldn't be happier.  I highly recommend them.

Comment: Testflight should update their document for sure :) I have tried for an hour atleast before finding this post. Now added endSession to my phonegap app during my app pause event. And it started showing up in my session.

Comment: @DrewShafer your answer gave me some hope, but the comment later on seems to capture how things go downhill with TestFlight. After trying to wrap my head around it, I finally ditched TestFlight for Crashlytics. Pity they couldn't make the integration any less painful, esp at a time when you've got your competitor's products integrating in a jiffy!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make a comment on the checkpoint front. I can see checkpoints being reported straight away without needing to end sessions. Looks like they removed the batching on [Android](https://twitter.com/testflightapp/status/418894069402963968)

Answer (score 0):

We made it work by calling *TestFlight.startSession()* on our activities *onStart* and *TestFlight.endSession()* on *onStop*.

The extra steps are not documented in TestFlight SDK, but it seems to force the app to send session logs to TestFlight servers.